# Why css class being overridden?

Tags: html, css

I have a table.  I just want the 1st column to align left and other columns align right.  I use the following style:

```
<style>
    table{ width:100%;}
    .1col{ text-align:left;}
    .othercols{width:100px;}
    table>tbody>tr>td, table>tbody>tr>th { text-align:center;} 
</style>
```

Then I have my table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th class="1col">Category</th>
        <th class="othercols">Some text</th>
        <th class="othercols">Some text</th>
        <th class="othercols">Some text</th>
    </tr>
    <tr >
        <td class="1col">Some text</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The result is that my 1col class is ignored.  Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CSS Class can't start with an integer, so try `col1` instead.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/9X7kz/8/

Here's the full grammar if you are interested:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#scanner

And this is the specific rule spec:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in
>   selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646
>   characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore
>   (_); **they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed
>   by a digit.** Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any
>   ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance,
>   the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F".

Comment: You are right for the naming problem.  But why my th headings are all align left?  I means table>tbody>tr>th { text-align:center;} is not working?

Comment: Actually, `.col` has a higher specificity than `table>tbody>tr>td` (10 vs 4) see: http://jsfiddle.net/9X7kz/6/

Comment: @steveax thanks for pointing that out :s, I'll just delete those explanations entirely

Comment: Note that [in HTML5, the `id` attribute is much more permissive about characters](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id): "Any string, with the following restrictions: must be at least one character long;  must not contain any space characters".

Answer (score 1):

Anything descending selector in CSS (i.e. anything that selects from a parent, like `table>tbody>tr>th`) is more specific than a selector that is not descending (like any garden variety `div`, or `.class`).

In general you should avoid that level of specificity, as it will cause alot of problems (much like the one you're experiencing now).

The "direct child selector" only selects direct descendants, so here it's not really doing you any good, seeing that a `th` can *only* descend from a `tbody`, and  a `th` can only descend from a `tr`.

you should give the table a class and descend all of the styles pertaining to that element or children elements from that class.

Also, in CSS, styles that come further down in the stylesheet override the ones above, depending also on some other weighted factors (link is in steveax's comment below).

You need to place the `.1col` declaration further down for it to take priority... And, as per SiGanteng's answer... don't start class names with numbers.

```
.table{ width:100%;}
.table .othercols{width:100px;}
.table td, .table th { text-align:center;} 
.table .col1{ text-align:left;}
```

Comment: No, the "cascade" in CSS is not about order in the style sheet.

Comment: If you want to be helpful, you should say what it is, not what it isn't.

Comment: Perhaps [the cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade) will be helpful.

Comment: That is "cascade". Cascading order: "Finally, sort by order specified: if two declarations have the same weight, origin and specificity, the latter specified wins."

Comment: Right, if you ignore everything preceding that ;-) BTW, as I pointed out below, `.col1` has a higher specificity than `table>tbody>tr>td` so order is irrelevant in this case.

Answer (score 0):

change `1col` to `acol`. ***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/QBf7u/)*** is a working Live Demo. Is this you want?

Answer (score 0):

Working Code:

```
<style>
    table{ width:100%;}
    .col1{ text-align:left;}
    .othercols{width:100px;}
    table>tbody>tr>td, table>tbody>tr>th { text-align:center;} 
</style>

<table>
<tr>
    <th class="col1">Category</th>
    <th class="othercols">Some text</th>
    <th class="othercols">Some text</th>
    <th class="othercols">Some text</th>
</tr>
<tr >
    <td class="col1">Some text</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```